# How to invoke a device method with no method-payload (JSON: null) with azure CLI?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-cli

I'm using the Azure CLI to invoke methods of IoTHub devices. Previously with the iothub-explorer one could invoke methods without sending data (an empty string was considered a JSON `null`). Now with Azure CLI it seems impossible.

By default, method-payload is `{}` i.e. an empty JSON object. Setting the argument `--mp` to `""` or `''` is actually considered as an empty string which is sent as such.

Setting `--mp` to `null` (valid JSON), payload is sent as None which results as a NULL-pointer on the client side and not as a JSON `null`.

How to invoke a method with a JSON `null`-payload?

```
az iot hub invoke-device-method -n <hubname> -d <device> --mn <method> --mp ???
```

After some hacking I decided to create an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension/issues/309

Comment: try the following:  **--mp null** or --mp '{}'

Comment: `{}` is the default, empty object. `--mp null` sends a null-pointer-string. Which at least the C-iot-sdk does not like.

Comment: I just realized that I would want a JSON `null` to be sent - actually.

Comment: As per the related thread the bug is now fixed: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension/issues/309 . Patrick can you add the answer here as well?